# Spring boot 2.4 Reverse document order

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In spring boot 2.4, later loaded properties override earlier properties.

But, for my need, I am importing document inside document using spring.config.import. Say, import abc.properties from application.properties.

But, I need to override, later loaded properties with earlier loaded ones.
Say, application.properties should override abc.properties. not the other way arpund.

Please help me on how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the interest of overriding these properties if you do not want them to affect earlier properties ?

Comment: It is not about overriding. I have to load full set of properties from remote location based on local file path properties. And file path property is loaded based on application.properties. The idea is to override remote properties locally. So, effectively reversing the property order, while keeping document order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue with EnvironmentPostProcessor, as it seems to be not doable simply with spring.config.import.
As, both yaml (and in terns json) and properties, property source parser is readily available in spring boot, this required very little coding.